# How to use jsf 2.0 f:ajax option for render a popup box

Tags: jsf-2

```
   <div class="staff_ActionListTable">
    <h:panelGroup id="imccomponent">
        <div class="scroll-pane2Container">
            <div class="scroll-pane2" id="pane2">
                <div class="actionInnerTable">

                    <ui:repeat var="action" value="#{immediateActionListController.actionList}" varStatus="status">
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{status.even}">
                            <!--Update button-->
                            <h:commandButton  image="updateBtn.gif" value="Update1">
                                <f:ajax event="click" execute=":pp1" render=":pp1" listener="#{immediateActionListController.loadEditableActionComponent}" onevent="im_action_popupopener"/>
                                <f:param value="#{action.taskId}" name="immediateTaskIdForEdit">
                                </f:param>
                            </h:commandButton>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </ui:repeat>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>

<!--Add button-->
<div class="staffMember_ButtonContainer">
    <h:commandButton  image="addImmediateActionBtn.gif">
        <f:ajax event="click" execute="imccomponent" render="imccomponent" listener="#{immediateActionListController.loadAddActionPopUp}" onevent="action_im_add_popupopener"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</div>

<h:panelGroup id="pp1">
    <!--Popup1 start: Add Action-->
</h:panelGroup>
```

My code is like above, I want to bind particular values for 'pp1' pop-up box when I press the updateBtn button. That mean I want to render only that pop-up box part, then how I should specify execute, render option for this (I have try with execute=":pp1" render=":pp1" but it is not working). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `execute` is wrong. You need to execute the button itself, not the render target.

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render=":pp1" listener="#{immediateActionListController.loadEditableActionComponent}" onevent="action_im_add_popupopener"/>
```

Otherwise the listener is never called. Note that I removed the `event="click"` as it is the default already.

Comment: Hi BalusC! Thanks a lot for your feed back. You have denoted about my "Add button" know it works fine with those options, but I want to know about how to use those potions for my "Update button", When I re-factor that button way that you denoted as "<f:ajax execute="@this" render=":pp1" listener="#{immediateActionListController.loadEditableActionComponent}" onevent="im_action_popupopener"/>", I still getting exception as "javax.servlet.ServletException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':pp1' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt185
". Thanks.

Comment: Is it inside the same `<h:form>`? Give that an `id` like `<h:form id="myform">` and use `render=":myform:pp1"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add iframe, and add css for show popup mode and uses all navegation cases. this a simple sample.

When the case navegation is ok and the commponent has target attribute, this case navegation toViewId is show in the iframe (into panelFrame), and until iframe page navegation to a parentViewId, this iframe close and return to parent page

source https://github.com/yracnet/hiska-HskFrame/